# Calculated field based on values in other columns

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

I have a new SP 2013 List that I would like to add a new field with a calculated 'score' based on the values of a few other columns.

For example,

The Choices for Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4 are all High, Med or Low.
If High = 3, Med = 2 and Low =1, I would like to have a score field which is a sum of each Col1-4.

I am new to calculated formulas in SP, so would appreciate any help or reference.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Is given formula works for you?

Comment: Start building/learning your Formulas in Excel, they will translate 1:1 to SharePoint for all basic functions: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List\

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use below formula in calculated field.

```
=SUM(
       if([Col1]="High",3, if([Col1]="Med",2, if([Col1]="Low",1,0)))
     , if([Col2]="High",3, if([Col2]="Med",2, if([Col2]="Low",1,0)))
     , if([Col3]="High",3, if([Col3]="Med",2, if([Col3]="Low",1,0)))
     , if([Col4]="High",3, if([Col4]="Med",2, if([Col4]="Low",1,0)))
    )
```

Please let me know it works or not.